# Find a document using multiple fields mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to add a trade to my collection of trades only if a trade doesn't exist in the collection.

Here is my problem : the function **findPosition** seems to find some trades even tough my collection is empty. Therefore, no new trades are added to my collection.

Here is the code :

```js
async function createPostion(params, uid){
  let position = new OpenPositionModel({
    uid : uid,
    symbol : params.symbol,
    entryPrice: params.entryPrice
  });
  return position.save();
}

async function findPosition(uid, symbol, entryPrice){
  return OpenPositionModel.findOne({
    $and: [
        {uid: uid},
        {symbol: symbol},
        {entryPrice: entryPrice}
    ]
  });
}

async function createNewPostion(params, uid){
  let res = findPosition(uid, params.symbol, params.entryPrice);
  if(!res){
    createPostion(params, uid);
  }
}
```

I have tried to use the $and operator to make sure a trade is found by the uid of the trader, the symbol and the entryPrice.

If nothing is found in a collection my cursor should by null right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the `Promise` returned by `findPosition` to be resolved, within `createNewPosition`:

```
async function createNewPostion(params, uid){
  let res = await findPosition(uid, params.symbol, params.entryPrice);
  if(!res){
    createPostion(params, uid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I also added ```await``` to ```createPostion```